# How to use is_callable with __call?

Tags: php, call, overloading, overriding, magic-methods

I use PHP 5.3, which introduces closures. Because I now have closures available throughout my app (and framework), I use is_callable to see what kind of handler `$callback` is.

If `$callback` `is_callable`, I know enough and use that function/method/closure. If it's not callable and it's a string, it's probably the name of a method in `$this` class. It might exist and it might not. If I let it up to PHP, it will 'throw' a nice fatal error (I like those).

But I want to use [mix-ins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) which means I need the magic method `__call`. `__call` is very cool, because it (can) contain(s) logic before the actual function call. **BUT**... what happens if after `__call` the called method doesn't exist? I can throw an exception, sure, but we won't know until after.

The problem is now the usefulness of `is_callable`, because after implementing `__call`, **everything** will return true, because everything has a fallback (being `__call`).

Is there a way to have both: dynamic methods and useful `is_callable`?

What I'd love to see is some sort of cachable magic method `__is_callable` that PHP will 'consult' when `is_callable(array($object, $method))` is called.

On php.net, I can't find anyone who is as bumbed about this as me. This can't be it! If you use `__call`, you can't use `is_callable` anymore!?

Am I making any sense?

**PS.** I've looked into `method_exists` but that's just not good enough (even if I can filter out all closures and global functions) because it will return true for private and protected methods as well as public.

**edit**
I made [a 'better' is_callable that checks for mix-ins](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/Rudie-on-wheels/blob/master/vendors/row/core/Extendable.php) but I think it's pretty expensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea: how about checking if method exists in `get_class_methods()`? This function takes care of scope issues.

Second idea: if function you're looking for doesn't exist in a class, you could also check (using `method_exists`) if class contains `__call` magic method, if it doesn't than obviously call to a non-existing function is illegal. If class contains `__call` method, it's likely that caller knows what he's doing.

These are just my thoughts, I assume Python to be better in this kind of things.

Comment: `get_class_methods` did solve another problem, but not really the mix-ins. This very important part is not really true: "If class contains `__call` method, it's likely that caller knows what he's doing." because you might set a renderer for 10 classes that only 4 classes have (and use) and the other 6 will use the standard, but you only have to set it once now. (Wow, did you get that?)